# Parameter query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a simple script that brings through, for a certain product, the date it was ordered and the date the order was completed.

On a graph, I am tring to show the number ordered between a certain date and the number completed between the same date.

The problem I face is that in the script I have used:

AND job.orderdate BETWEEN (@odate1) AND (odate2)

This is absolutely fine for displaying new orders. However, when I use the same parameter for completed orders, it obviously only shows the jobs that were completed between the above parameter.

For example, if I put in November's date parameters, it will show me:

50 orders
25 jobs completed

What it will not show me is if a job completed in November where the order did not begin in November. So I may have an instance where 15 other jobs were completed in November, but because their start date was say October, they will not come through.

Can anyone suggest a way of bringing this data through? All I am trying to do is present a graph that shows: new orders and completed orders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show Job Orders between some date, or Jobs Completed between some dates, the query surely needs to use an OR statement

```
WHERE ...
AND ((job.orderdate BETWEEN (@odate1) AND (odate2)) 
OR (job.completeddate BETWEEN (@odate1) AND (odate2)))
```

This will show all records wehere the orderdate or the completed date is between `@odate1` and `odate2`

**Also**

Using BETWEEN with dates can get you into **[all sorts of trouble](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

It is better to use > and < comparisons to a known date.  Rewriting the above in this methodology would be

```
WHERE ...
AND (((job.orderdate >= @odate1) AND (job.orderdate <= odate2)) 
OR ((job.completeddate >= @odate1) AND (job.completeddate <= odate2)))
```

**UPDATE**

You can set separate flags for each record to show whether it meets the criteria for

- Ordered in this date period
- Completed in this date period

Using CASE statements as below

```
SELECT ...
    CASE 
        WHEN ((job.orderdate >= @odate1) AND (job.orderdate <= odate2)) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS OrderInPeriod
    CASE 
        WHEN ((job.completeddate >= @odate1) AND (job.completeddate <= odate2)) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS CompletedInPeriod
FROM myTABLE
WHERE ...
AND (((job.orderdate >= @odate1) AND (job.orderdate <= odate2)) 
OR ((job.completeddate >= @odate1) AND (job.completeddate <= odate2)))
```

You could then SUM in the report based on these flags, or filter the tablix based on these filters, or use them in another manner in your report, i.e.

Create a new Tablix filter, with the expression set to

```
 =iif((Fields!OrderInPeriod.Value = 1) OR (Fields!CompletedInPeriod.Value = 1), 1, 0)
```

Then the Operater = "=" and the Value = 1

To filter out all records that are neither `OrderInPeriod` or `CompletedInPeriod` set to 1

Comment: Thanks for getting back Jonnus. What you've suggested nearly works, in that it now brings though the correct number of completed orders. However, in doing this it has included the orders that were started before the parameter dates! So for example it now shows, for November, 70 orders, 18 completed. It should show 65 ordered (as were between the parameter) and 18 completed.

Comment: Was this not what you meant by *"if a job completed in November where the order did not begin in November."* in the original question...

Comment: Yes - but that was before I tried your AND / OR solution. So I'm a bit stuck. I'd love the graph to show how many items were ordered and how many completed, irrespective of when they completed. Thanks for the warning re BETWEEN.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want all completed records between the dates irrespective of start date (*how many completed, irrespective of when they completed*), and how many items were ordered between the dates (*how many items were ordered*)

Comment: Is that not what it is showing currently?  You state that it is showing 70 records when there should be 65.  What are the properties of these other 5 records?  They have been returned either because they completed between the dates, or they were ordered between the dates.  Is this due to the use of the = sign and in fact you want the start and/or end dates excluded from the result set?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The properties of the 5 records are that they started before the parameter dates; they show because they completed within the dates. So I can see why they're there; however ideally they would only show in the total of completed, not in new orders, so I'd see, for example, 65 new orders in the time I've specified, 18 completed. So basically I need the total of completed to show whenever the order was started (as long as the completed date is between the date parameters) and the order date itself to show strictly between the date parameters.

Comment: Last question (I think). Are you returning all the records and performing the calculation in SSRS, or are your grouping and/or summing in the SQL?  I ask as it would be good to add a few extra fields to indicate which were completed in the time period only - or which were new orders in the time period...

Comment: I'm returning and performing the calculation in SSRS. Any ideas welcome, thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and patience Jonnus. That has worked.